# Why $|P(\mathbb N)|>|\mathbb N|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Why $|\mathbb N|<|P(\mathbb N)|$ ?**

($P(\mathbb N)$ is the power set of \mathbb N).

First of all i know that
$|P(\mathbb N)|=|\mathbb R|.$

By using binary decimals injective function:$P(\mathbb N) \to (0,1) \in \mathbb R \implies  |P(\mathbb N)|\leq|\mathbb R|.$

But why i cant defined $f : P(\mathbb N) \to \mathbb N $ by mapping each number subset of $\mathbb N$ ?

An example :

define g: $P(\mathbb N) \to \mathbb N$ with mapping each number in a subset of $\mathbb N$.

$g({1,2,6}) = 110001.$

$g({12,15}) = 000000000001001.$
(g looks injective function to me).

What i'm missing ?

Comment: What is $P(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: Hint: what is $g(\{\text{even numbers}\})$?

Comment: @erez What if the set is infinite?

Comment: I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: First show that you can map the subsets of $\mathbb N$ bijective to the set of infinite long binary strings. Then, Cantor's diagonal method easily shows that there are uncountable many infinite binary strings and therefore also  uncountable many subsets of $\mathbb N$

Comment: You say $g(12,15) = 000000000001001$.  What about $g(1,4)$?  Wouldn't that be $1001$?  Isn't $1001 = 000000000001001$?  So, for starters, your function isn't injective.  Sure, you can fix that by appending a $1$ at the front... The bigger problem though is as alluded to already, $g(\{n~:~n~\text{even}\})$ would be what?  $010101010101010101\cdots$?  Is that an element of $\Bbb N$?  No?  What does that imply about your proposed "function"?

Comment: As an aside, your work so far *can* be modified and used to show that the set $\{A~:~A\subseteq \Bbb N,~|A|~\text{finite}\}$ *is* the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$.